# Add digit only to one digit number in middle of text libreoffice regex

Tags: libreoffice

I want to append one zero to part of text using regular expression in Writer, like this:

```
Gr 5
Gr 15
Gr 7
```

became:

```
Gr 05
Gr 15
Gr 07
```

This texts is last words in paragraphs

Comment: I found result:Find &Replace with: (Gr )([:digit:])$ in find box and Gr 0$2 in Replace box and regular expression checked

Answer (score 0):

Even easier: set Find to `Gr ([:digit:])$` and Replace to `Gr 0$1`, i.e. you can get away with just a single group.